# Set Vue.js language base on Django LANGUAGE_CODE

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, vuejs2

I had a Django project where i use Vue.js for some parts. I've translated all django parts and i now how to translate all Vue.js parts. 
Language switcher is on Django template page and it's changing language in all django project and apps respectively.
I need to get current Django LANGUAGE_CODE and use it for setting Vue.js language.

This is a short version of *app.js* (somehow a point of entry for my Vue.js) where i import *translations.json* with a translations and setting Vue.js language

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VModal from 'vue-js-modal';
import GetTextPlugin from 'vue-gettext';
import translations from '../../locale/translations';


const settings = {
  apiKey: '',
  lang: 'ru_RU',
  coordorder: 'latlong',
  version: '2.1',
};

Vue.use(GetTextPlugin, {
  availableLanguages: {
    en_US: 'American English',
    ru_RU: 'Russian',
  },
  defaultLanguage: 'ru_RU',
  translations,
});
```

If i change field *defaultLanguage: 'LANGUAGE'* in *GetTextPlugin* it will change the language for Vue.js. So i need to know how to get Django current language to set it here.

**UPDATE**

Did as dirkgroten say.
But now error in Vue appear *"error 'LANGUAGE' is not defined no-undef"*

**base.html**

```
{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
<script>let LANGUAGE = {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }};</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  {% include 'chunks/head.html' %}
  <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
{% include 'chunks/svg.html' %}
<div class="preloader">
  <div class="preloader__icon"></div>
</div>
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}

{% block popup %}{% endblock popup %}
{% block script %}
  {% include 'chunks/scripts.html' %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**Vue.js**

```
Vue.use(GetTextPlugin, {
  availableLanguages: {
    en_US: 'American English',
    ru_RU: 'Russian',
  },
  defaultLanguage: LANGUAGE,
  translations,
});
```

Comment: Keep the language in the URL. Something like what Instagram does: `instagram.com/?hl=en`. This way, your django code and vue code can set the language by reading the parameter value from the url.

Comment: You can set a javascript variable in your base template: `{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %} const LANGUAGE = {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}`

Comment: @xyres Will Vue.js set language from url by default or i should do it mannualy?

Answer (score 0):

Set a javascript constant in your base template:

```
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
<script>const LANGUAGE = "{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}"</script>
```

Comment: Did as you say. 
This is base.html
`{% load i18n %}`
`{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}`
`<script>let LANGUAGE = {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }};</script>`



This is Vue.js
`Vue.use(GetTextPlugin, {`
 ` availableLanguages: {`
  `  en_US: 'American English',`
 `   ru_RU: 'Russian',`
 ` },`
`  defaultLanguage: LANGUAGE,`
`  translations,`
`});`
But now error in Vue appear "error  'LANGUAGE' is not defined  no-undef"

Comment: check the order in which the scripts are read. Is the `let LANGUAGE = ` above the vue.js script? Also just to be sure check the html source. I added quotes, I think they're needed.

Comment: Yes, moreover Vue.js can see LANGUAGE as a global variable.

Please, check UPDATE section in my question